# Genetic Algorithm: Find a curve function that separates 2 sets of points

Tags: algorithm, math, artificial-intelligence, computer-science, genetic-algorithm

I'm working on a genetic algorithm to find a curve of different degrees (polynomials values) that separates two sets of point.

All points from the first set should be above and all the points form the second set should be below the curve function.

- Input is a degree of a polynomial (e.g. 2, 3 and/or 4)
- Output should be polynomial (e.g. **y = A*x^3 + B*x^2 + C** where A, B and C are values we are looking for on the process. Each of them has a genes and chromosomes consisting of their X,Y coordinate.)

I'm having a trouble with finding a right fitness function and selection methods for it.

Is there any better solution and/or approach for this problem?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why 10 and -5? Seems too crude. Something like sum of squares of the deviations of misclassified points would give more information for your algorithm to work on. You want to reward attempted solutions which are *close* to being correct.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks for quick reply. This was the easiest way that came to my mine, just to sum **correctPointsAmount*10+wrongPointsAmount*(-5)**. What do you mean by misclassified points here? And how your solution is supposed to look like?

Comment: Really a ML question. http://peterroelants.github.io/posts/neural_network_implementation_part02/

Comment: If you want/must use a GA that's fine, but just for the record, that problem is exactly what [SVMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) (in this case with a [polynomial kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel)) solve.